# Can I give fruit syrup and soda syrup to birds in winter?

Tags: food-waste

I have several bottles of syrup which I am never gonna consume.
And I would prefer not to simply throw away their content.

I plan to put them in cups, near the place I put butter/margarine for birds in winter. It's freezing these days.

I have not seen clear information against doing so, whether it is good or bad for birds to drink almost pure sugar and so on...

Any idea, before I do it all the same, lacking info on the subject ?

Or any other idea how to use them.

Comment: Would you be interested in other potential uses, besides just feeding birds?

Answer (score 4):

From many references, [e.g. this good one](http://birding.about.com/od/birdfeeders/a/winterfeeding.htm),

> The best foods to offer birds in colder weather have a high fat or oil content that will provide abundant energy for winter survival. Nutritious winter foods for birds include:
>
> - Black oil sunflower seed
> - Hulled peanuts or peanut hearts
> - Nyjer (thistle) seed
> - Suet mixes with seeds or fruit
> - Peanut butter
>     ...

**Not sugar!** I suspect this is like for humans. It will quickly relieve the lack of energy, but the effect will fall back very quickly too. Sugar won't help birds to have long lasting energy in the belly.

What you could do with this liquid sugar is to pour it on the ground to **fertilize your yard**. Fungus and Microorganisms will thrive on it as soon as little heat comes back with bright sunny days, and decompose it to good soil for e.g. fruit trees. Of course this could bring you insects too, so don't put it too close to your home. I advise you use the most remote place of your yard, beside your compost.

Comment: + attracting insects would help feed birds in the location...